# Recently changed domain name. Home page widgets are now not in the customize menu yet still being on the page

Tags: widgets

I recently changed the domain name on my wordpress website. Since doing so I am unable to edit the current widgets I have on the home page. They are still on the actual home page however when I go into customization I see the following "Your theme has 8 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them on page with widgets".

I can still edit them in the widgets area but I am concerned why I cant do it the normal way in customization. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the two are related. Were any other changes made to the site besides the change of domain name? Is it a paid-theme / plugin which is licensed only for a specific domain?

Comment: I have made a few other minor changes with plugins. I have used a health check plugin to remove all plugins and even with just the theme on there I am unable to access the widgets as the theme believes there is no widget areas on that page. In my opinion it feels as if when in customizer the theme is not realising it is the home page. It is working fine for the other 2 pages that have widget areas (shop & Blog).

Comment: No paid theme or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something in the database is still referencing the old domain name?

Use a plug like "Better Search and Replace" to search (only) the database for your old domain name. (If you are brave, you can use SQL commands to do that. But that plugin - or similar - are much easier.)

(You may need to do a search/replace anyhow, as media file links will have the old domain name.)

Backups are important before any major changes.

Comment: Reporting back on how you got this fixed is helpful to others, as is marking the answer correct (if it was). Just use the "Add Comment", or, if the solution was different, add your own answer.